# Issue with column names CLUSTER & COMMENT during merge/insert command in oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

I am having a table where two columns are having reserved keywords of oracle named CLUSTER & COMMENT. I am trying to use the merge command from spring JDBC which is throwing the below error.

**ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification**

```
MERGE INTO TABLE DESTINATION 
USING ( SELECT  ? AS NAME, ? AS CLUSTER, ? AS COMMENT FROM DUAL) SOURCE 
ON (SOURCE.NAME = DESTINATION.NAME) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET DESTINATION.CLUSTER = SOURCE.CLUSTER, DESTINATION.COMMENT = SOURCE.COMMENT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (NAME, CLUSTER, COMMENT) 
VALUES (SOURCE.NAME, SOURCE.CLUSTER,SOURCE.COMMENT)
```

Can some please help me how to resolve this without changing the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use [reserved words](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10830/appb.htm) as identifers then you need to use quoted identifiers (and the exact case used in the database):

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name DESTINATION 
USING (
  SELECT ? AS NAME,
         ? AS "CLUSTER",
         ? AS "COMMENT"
  FROM   DUAL
) SOURCE 
ON (SOURCE.NAME = DESTINATION.NAME) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE
  SET DESTINATION."CLUSTER" = SOURCE."CLUSTER",
      DESTINATION."COMMENT" = SOURCE."COMMENT"
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (NAME, "CLUSTER", "COMMENT")
  VALUES (SOURCE.NAME, SOURCE."CLUSTER",SOURCE."COMMENT");
```

However, a better solution would be to change the identifiers to non-reserved words.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=910a305a59f3981dac07e207ae69e729)*